# HTML5/Javascript - My user-triggered canvas animation choppy

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a simple concept. When the player presses W, A, S, or D, an image on the canvas moves accordingly. However, this results in very choppy animation, and I'm not sure why(though I think it has something to do with my event listeners). Below is my code.

```
var playerXPos = 10;
var playerYPos = 10;
var playerImg = new Image();
playerImg.src = "knight.png";

function mainGameLoop(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(mainGameLoop);
    c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");


    c.clearRect(0,0,1000,500);

    c.drawImage(playerImg,playerXPos,playerYPos);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(mainGameLoop);


    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
    window.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress, false);

    function onKeyDown(e){
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        switch(keyCode){
            case 87: //w
                onKeyW();
            break;
            case 65: //a
                onKeyA();
            break;
            case 83: //s
                onKeyS();
            break;
            case 68: //d
                onKeyD();
            break;
        }



function onKeyW(){
    playerYPos -= 5;
}
function onKeyA(){
    playerXPos -= 5;
}
function onKeyS(){
    playerYPos += 5;
}
function onKeyD(){
    playerXPos += 5;
}
```

Why is it doing this? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** As a side note, I have done this before using booleans(when the w key is pressed a `keyW` variable becomes true, and in the mainGameLoop there is `if(keyW == true){playerYPos -= 5;}`)

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dNtu/3/)**

Comment: for one you probably want handleKeyboard() outside of your game loop method. This method only needs to be called once to register the event handlers.

Comment: The `playerXPos += 5;` lines may be causing some choppiness as it moves the image 5px at a time which is quite a large jump.

Comment: I changed it to 1 and it is still very choppy, simply at a slower rate

Comment: @jezternz This helps somewhat, however, it is still very choppy

Comment: Can you make it on http://jsfiddle.net so people can try it?

Comment: Moving this to be outside the loop will also help: var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");

Comment: Jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7dNtu/3/).The code is a bit more messy(I simplified what I put here on stack overflow for the sake of readability)

Comment: The JSfiddle acts pretty much as I would expect it to, a little jerky, but changing the speed to 1, removes that jerkyness.

Comment: @jezterns Although it still looks jerky to me, what am I supposed to do if I want it to go faster?

Comment: I apologize Teh, I am not overly confident with 2d canvas animation, hopefully someone else will have a good answer :)

Comment: You should probably declare c outside the main game loop function so you don't have to keep getting the context, not sure how much time this saves but I would assume it should do something.

Comment: @jezternz Much appreciated, though this question seems to be dead. I might have to find another way to solve this problem

Comment: @Jack I have done this, and it throws an error(Cannot call method 'getContext' of null). Not entirely sure why.

Comment: It sounds like you ran the code before the page loaded you will need to wrap the code in an onload event listener.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, however, that still doesn't solve my real problem

Comment: you might want to look into tweenjs or some tweening library to see if you can incorporate that into your character movement, that may make the movement a little bit smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/7dNtu/4/)

You don't want to change the position each key event.  Also, you need to take into account the time between frames.  Adding any static amount per frame will always be jumpy, since one frame might be 30ms since the last or it might be 60ms, depending on many factors.

```
var playerXPos = 10;
var playerYPos = 10;
var playerSpeed = 0.3; // this is in pixels per ms

var aPressed = false;
var wPressed = false;
var sPressed = false;
var dPressed = false;
var lastTime = null;
function mainGameLoop(timestamp) {
    var delta = timestamp - (lastTime || timestamp);

    if(aPressed){
        playerXPos -= playerSpeed * delta;
    }
    if(dPressed){
        playerXPos += playerSpeed * delta;
    }
    if(wPressed){
        playerYPos -= playerSpeed * delta;
    }
    if(sPressed){
        playerYPos += playerSpeed * delta;
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(mainGameLoop);
    c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");

    c.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    player();
    lastTime = timestamp;
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(mainGameLoop);

function player() {
    var playerImg = new Image();
    //playerImg.src = "knight.png";
    c.fillRect(playerXPos, playerYPos,100,100);
}

function onKeyW(pressed) {
    wPressed = pressed;
}

function onKeyA(pressed) {
    aPressed = pressed;
}

function onKeyS(pressed) {
    sPressed = pressed;
}

function onKeyD(pressed) {
    dPressed = pressed;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

function onKeyDown(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 87:
            //w
            onKeyW(true);
            console.log("bro");
            break;
        case 65:
            //a
            onKeyA(true);
            break;
        case 83:
            //s
            onKeyS(true);
            break;
        case 68:
            //d
            onKeyD(true);
            break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);

function onKeyUp(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 87:
            //w
            onKeyW(false);
            console.log("bro");
            break;
        case 65:
            //a
            onKeyA(false);
            break;
        case 83:
            //s
            onKeyS(false);
            break;
        case 68:
            //d
            onKeyD(false);
            break;
    }
}
```